# draw a dotted line on CorePlot graph in iOS

Tags: ios, core-plot

How to draw a dotted line on graph using core plot plot, that line is for maximum and minimum range of axis.

In AndroidPlot, ValueMarker is for drawing a maximum and minimum horizontal line on graph.

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: You should add two more plots that will represent two horizontal lines.

Comment: Thanks alot Stanley, How can I draw dotted line on graph?

Comment: I added code where I have a dashed line, but using the same way you can get dotted line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I used for such situation:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CPTScatterPlot *myLine;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CPTGraph *graph;

    -(void) configureHorizontalLine
    {
        // 1 - Create plot space
        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;

        // 2 - Create the plot
        self.myLine = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
        self.myLine.dataSource = self;
        self.myLine.identifier = @"myLine";

        CPTColor *myPlotColor = [CPTColor redColor];
        [self.graph addPlot:self.myLine toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

        // 3 - Create styles
        CPTMutableLineStyle *myPlotLineStyle = [self.myLine.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];

        myPlotLineStyle.dashPattern=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:3],nil];  //dashed line

        myPlotLineStyle.lineWidth = 1;
        myPlotLineStyle.lineColor = myPlotColor;
        self.myLine.dataLineStyle = myPlotLineStyle;
    }
```

Also in `CPTPlotDataSource` methods you must do the following check to identify line plot:

```
if ([[plot identifier] isEqual:@"myLine"])
```